Probability and Order of Operations
I am confused...




Car
Bike
Bus
Other




Freshman
10
5
7
2


Sophomore
20
10
11
5


Junior
25
20
31
4


Senior
18
17
16
14



If I do P(Freshman | Bus) the answer would be P(Freshman given Bus) or how many people in the group "Bus" (i.e. [7, 11, 31, 16]) are freshman which is
7/(7 + 11 + 31 + 16) = 7/65
However, if I do P(Car | Sophomore or Senior)...
I can either consider it P((Car | Sophomore) or Senior) or P(Car | (Sophomore or Senior))
If I assume P((Car | Sophomore) or Senior):
Given the logic P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)
And given the logic P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B),
I can construct the logic also that P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A) * P(B)
I would assume:
P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A) * P(B)
Translates to
P((Car | Sophomore) or Senior) = P(Car | Sophomore) + P(Senior) - P(Car | Sophomore) * P(Senior)
To solve the sub-equations:
P(Car | Sophomore) = 20 / (20 + 10 + 11 + 5) = 20/46 = 0.43478
P(Senior) = (18 + 17 + 16 + 14) / (18 + 17 + 16 + 14 + 25 + 20 + 31 + 4 + 5 + 11 + 10 + 20 + 2 + 7 + 5 + 10) = 65/215 = 0.30233
That means:
P((Car | Sophomore) or Senior) = 0.43478 + 0.30233 - 0.43478 * 0.30233
P((Car | Sophomore) or Senior) = 0.60566
If I assume P(Car | (Sophomore or Senior)):
I can just add up the [sophmore, car] cell and [senior, car] cell and divide the result by the total of seniors and total of sophomores:
P(Car | (Sophomore or Senior)) = (20 + 18) / (20 + 10 + 11 + 5 + 18 + 17 + 16 + 14)
P(Car | (Sophomore or Senior)) = 38 / 111
P(Car | (Sophomore or Senior)) = 0.34234
My confusion:
When should I apply joint probability vs marginal probability? Also am I missing something as to what is preferred order of operations or am I making things up?

As explained in this answer to the  linked duplicate q., Car | Sophomore is not an event, so the interpretation P((Car | Sophomore) or Senior) is meaningless.
